# Presto server crashing causes master node to restart

Tags: presto

I am working on a 3 node presto cluster and trying to run tpch queries on 100GB data on hive-orc. Whenever I execute a query, firstly it tries to execute the query but after a few seconds it crashes and my master node restarts. I could not figure out the problem from the logs, as there are no ERROR logs on my master or slaves nodes.

I have a cluster of 3 nodes with 45 GB of RAM each with presto 0.187.

So what could be the reason for the presto-server crash?

I am trying to execute the below query:

```
create table part with (format='orc') as select * from tpch.sf100.part;
```

Comment: Can you check the logs and presto worker settings especially memory settings? could be the case that data fetched for query is not fitting in memory space.

Comment: logs do not have any information regarding failure. These are my configurations.            
query.max-memory=40GB
query.max-memory-per-node=23GB
task.concurrency=2

Comment: DDL query should throw user error if it has failed. Looks suspicious if nothing is there in logs. Not sure if you should use "tpch.sf100.part;" or "tpch.sf100" with presto. can you just select count query on this table to see is it working?

Comment: The query has stuck again. And i can see that my remote machine is rebooted.

Comment: what do you mean by remote machine? A presto worker or data source. Above line signs like because remote machine was rebooted, your query was stuck. Correct me if I am wrong. I think you can try few things, 1. Try with small sized data and smaller query timeouts 2. identify the problem first? is it big data size (first point will make this clear), presto master, presto worker ? try monitoring all nodes (logs and resource util) and minimize possible options for failure. Because guess work without error/logs is not going get us to root of problem.

Comment: I am using hetzner cluster and connecting to it via ssh. There, i am running count(*) on 100gb data via presto which is failing. When my data size is small it runs without any problem(like on 50 GB it ran successfully) My master node is rebooting every time while worker throws an error as it is continuously failing to connect to master as the master is killed and the machine is rebooted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167562/discussion-between-sangeeta-and-nachiket-kate).